# how to get value of text wrapped in paragraph element <p> with selenium in java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I have a button, clicking on it generates a number which is wrapped in paragraph text such as `<p>random number <p>`, I want to get that random number value and do operations based on number it generates. From below I need to get `34,756` number and store it in java here is the html code for it:

```
<div class="form-group">
<div class="alert alert-count">
  <p>
  <b>
<!-- react-text: 531 -->
<!-- /react-text -->
<!-- react-text: 532 -->
 34,756
<!-- /react-text -->
</b>
```

and the xpath I used is as below

```
String count = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='alert alert-count']/p[1]/b).getText();
```

but on console it gives error as

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Is `By.xpath("//div[@class='alert alert-count']/p)` working?

Comment: yes..it is working correctly, only problem is to get that value in a string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using following:

```
  String count = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.alert.alert-count p")).getText();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this below code using `xpath locator`

```
String element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='alert alert-count']/p/b")).getText();
System.out.println(element);
```

**Explanation of xpath:-** Use `class` attribute of `<div>` tag and move ahead with `<p>` and `<b>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code using XPath locator

```
String element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='alert alert-count']")).getText();
System.out.println(element);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this locally here (in Python) and it works.

The XPath syntax seems to be:

```
//p[@class='classname']
```

**Example:**

Object I'm trying to grab:

```
<p class="randomtext">Random Text</p>
```

Code to get the object:

```
var = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, value="//p[@class='randomtext']")
print(var.text)
>>> Random Text
```